# Mutt e-mail client development ended?

Tags: mutt

Has development on Mutt (the e-mail client) ended? I can't figure it out from the Wiki page. How would I go about pushing a patch upstream if I had one? (so far, I just have something that works for me).

Incidentally: are there many people using it still nowadays? Why no development on it for months?

I looked here: http://dev.mutt.org/hg/mutt/

Comment: no idea, but this has my concern too

Comment: The right place for such application questions is Super User: [Newest 'mutt' Questions - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mutt).  (And a few months of quietness in a project that is many years old isn't a big deal at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, there's been quite some activity since your post:

http://dev.mutt.org/hg/mutt/